# VSO Webhook not trigger (work item updated)

Tags: webhooks, azure-devops

I am currently trying to set the webhook (for visualStudio.com). I managed to to make the event 'Work item commented' work.

Now i try to set up the event 'Work item updated'. when i create the hook, the test is successfull (captured with http://requestb.in/). I save the webhook then go to edit any issue (I've selected all work item type and all fields) but i doesnt trigger the webhook. (no errors, just no webhook sent...)

Is there something special that need to be actived to make the work item updated trigger active?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the Visual Studio Team Service issue, Microsoft is working on a deployment for this. Refer to this link for details: [ServiceHooks notification issues with Visual Studio Team Services - 1/27 - Mitigating](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsoservice/archive/2016/01/27/servicehooks-notification-issues-with-visual-studio-team-services-1-27-mitigating.aspx)

Comment: This issue has been fixed now, please try again.